# how browsers like firefox and chrome find mime type from file upload

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I'm creating a converter for files in disk of server that create mime type when reading file(lots of files in disk). I want to find a standard and true way of finding mime type. like the way most browsers do.
I know that there are some other ways like reading from extension and finding mime from a list that created by hand or using windows Urlmon.dll. but I want something really standard.
I've read rfc articles but didn't find what I really need.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no standard way doing that for all platforms. One of the examples I know about is in GO language implementation. (mime package)

See http://golang.org/pkg/mime/ for overview and description

For implementation details you can look into the package sources:
http://golang.org/src/pkg/mime/type.go
http://golang.org/src/pkg/mime/type_unix.go

Hope this helps you...

Comment: I saw these links I think It uses that way that I mentioned top that using a file with list of extension and mime types. so you don't what know other browsers developers did? are there any developer from team of chrome and firefox active here?

Comment: nobody else could answer? really there is no standard way for recognizing mime types from file in disk, when reading the file?